# apache tomcat 7 combined Realm

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat7, authorization

Is it possible to use [combined realm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm) in order to authenticate users vs the Active directory and then get the roles for the user from SQL database?
If yes please explain how and if no is please tell me if there is other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible but you can subclass the `JNDIRealm` and override the `getRoles` method.

Comment: I admit my mistake. Carry on!